# How can I create the decision tree below?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, forest

Can someone help me with this figure? I need to add it to a Latex document and I don't know how to use function properly.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable code you tried so far ...

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?") Have a look around the site, e.g. at [Problems with flow chart - decision tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320834/3323), to try to get started.

Comment: Part of my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex/254926?s=4|1.6430#254926 introduces Forest and may be helpful if you do it this way and are not, say, a linguist familiar with the bracket representation it uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as starting point with `forest`:

[image]

the text in nodes, nodes size and style you should accommodate to your needs/taste.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

    \begin{document}
%%%%    uvod-5
\linespread{0.9}
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
        text width = 22mm, text badly centered,
              % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
           anchor = north,
             grow = south,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 2mm,    %
            l sep = 4mm,    %
         fork sep = 2mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
         tier/.option=level,
               }
[text
    [no
        [text]
    ]
    [yes
        [text text
            [text text text
                [text
                    [text]
                ]
                [text
                    [text]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to close this as a duplicate?