# Tikz Four Groups

Tags: nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

I am aiming to make a flow diagram as drawn [image: here]however I have not been able to add the four boxes and include the top box centered. Also note the top box should be a full box. Please assist if you could!

I try to add [image: this] but does not come out right. Here is the code:

```
     [,name=Parent
   [,name=Parent1
    [,no edge,name=Child1
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild1]
    ]  
    [,no edge,name=Child2
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild2]
    ]  
    [,no edge,name=Child3
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild3]
    ]  
    [,no edge,name=Child4
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild4]
    ]  
  ] ]
**\draw[->] (Parent.west) -| (Parent1.north);**
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility: let forest place the boxes, suppress the edges and draw them afterwards.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{forest}
for tree={inner sep=2pt,outer
sep=0pt,align=center,font=\sffamily\footnotesize,draw,minimum width=3cm,
minimum height=0.5cm},
  [,name=Parent
    [,no edge,name=Child1
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild1]
    ]  
    [,no edge,name=Child2
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild2]
    ]  
    [,no edge,name=Child3
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild3]
    ]  
    [,no edge,name=Child4
      [,no edge,name=GrandChild4]
    ]  
  ]
\draw[->] (Parent.west) -| (Child1.north);  
\coordinate (x2) at ($(Child2.north)!0.5!(Child2.north east)$);
\draw[->] (Parent.south -| x2) -- (x2);  
\coordinate (x3) at ($(Child3.north)!0.5!(Child3.north west)$);
\draw[->] (Parent.south -| x3) -- (x3);  
\draw[->] (Parent.east) -| (Child4.north);  
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw[->] (Child\X) -- (GrandChild\X);}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that you could also do the whole thing in forest, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320834/121799), but I would like to argue that this is more effort.

Comment: This is really good thanks so much. Now what if I wanted to use the tikz environment because I already have a chart being designed in it. Say I have a box called A. How could I link the four boxes as shown in the original post (box2).

Comment: @Oscar First of all, forest is based on Ti*k*Z, and my example shows how you can give the boxes names such that they can be used as Ti*k*Z nodes (what they really are). Second, if you already have a Ti*k*Z code that you're working with, why don't you post it in your question?

Comment: @Oscar And everything starting from `\draw[->] (Parent.west) -| (Child1.north);` will work in your Ti*k*Z picture, you only need to adjust the node names.

Comment: Your code is much helpful but the text I wish to enter does not fit in the boxes and I am not able to fix this. I added a new image that I would hope to integrate into your code but again have much issue. You will see the new code in there as well.