# draw this block diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following picture. I have tried my best but nothing work. My document class memoir.
thanks.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Add that to your question.

Comment: You could use a [decision tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320834/121799).